# JQuery scrollTop values fadeIn/Out

Tags: jquery, fade, scrolltop

I have this code so that my '.button' would fadeIn if the 'scrollTop > 200'.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
            $('.button').fadeIn(500);
        } else {
            $('.button').fadeOut(500);
        }
    });
});
```

What I want to happen is I want '.button' to fadeIn if it's on a certain part of the page, and fadeOut if it's out of the specified part. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() 200 - 500) {
            $('.button').fadeIn(500);
        } else {
            $('.button').fadeOut(500);
        }
            });
});
```

Basically, I want ".button" to disappear if it's outside of the values given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to try something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scroll > 200 && scroll < 500) {
            $('.button').fadeIn(500);
        } else {
            $('.button').fadeOut(500);
        }
    });
});
```